# Use last Identity from insert query for another query

Tags: sql-server, insert, unique, identity

I want to insert to two table on sql-server , and use @@identity from first query:

```
INSERT INTO idcust(username, Email, Password, STATUS,
                   fullname, address, verificationCode, PhoneNo,
                   BOD, KTP, Gender, CreateDate)
VALUES(@UserName, @Email, dbo.fnMD5(@Password), @Status,
       @FullName, @Address, @VerificationCode, @PhoneNo,
       @BOD, @KTP, @Gender, getdate())

SET @IDAcc = @@IDENTITY

INSERT INTO Accounts(AccountNo, Provider, firstid, Status, 
                     FullName, [Address], Email, BOD, KTP,
                     PhoneNo, Gender)
VALUES(@Account, 'provider', @FirstIDAcc, @Status,
       @FullName, @Address, @Email, @bod, @KTP,
       @PhoneNo, @Gender)

SET @UserID = @@IDENTITY

IF @UserID > 0 BEGIN
   EXEC Email_FMCust @VerificationCode, @Email

   SET @Result = 1
   SET @RCode = 101
END
ELSE BEGIN
   SET @RCode = 216                 
END
```

But unfortunately both identity values from the two tables don't have any value, but for the first query the data inserted into table.

Is it table design fault? Or the query?

Comment: Do the tables have IDENTITY columns?

Comment: @Igor yes when I create the two tables I set identity for each tables

Comment: Try to use `SELECT @IDAcc = SCOPE_IDENTITY()` instead - use `SELECT` instead of `SET`, and use `SCOPE_IDENTITY` instead of `@@IDENTITY` - does that make a difference?